# Edit a string by replacing all "&" characters with another character in a .bat script

Tags: batch-file

I would like to edit a string in a .bat script to replace all "&" characters in it. The string will be used as a part of a path for an ffmpeg command.

Here is a simplified version of what I tried:

1/

```
set string=aaa&bbb&ccc
set "string=%string:&=_%"
echo %string%
```

this give:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>set string=aaa  & bbb & ccc
'bbb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'ccc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

2/

```
set string="aaa&bbb&ccc"
set "string=%string:&=_%"
echo %string%
```

this gives a correct result but with " which causes problems later on with the ffmpeg command:

```
"aaa_bbb_ccc"
```

I basically want to have the second result but without ".

I do not want to use PowerShell. A custom library is fine. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

(Edited for more details)

Comment: Your code works, but only outside of code blocks. You should show more of your code. At best a minimal, complete example

Comment: I edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the handling of variables.

The first problem is you `set string=aaa&bbb&ccc`.
This can't work, because the `&` will be handled as command separator.

`echo %string%` fails, when there is a `&` in your string.
If you expands a variable with batch, then the content will still be parsed for special characters.

To handle these problems, you can use the extended SET-Syntax.
And delayed expansion to access the content

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=aaa&bbb&ccc"
echo Before: !string!
set "string=!string:&=_!"
echo After: !string!
```

Comment: Let me recommend to enable delayed expansion after variable assignment, so it may even contain `!` and/or `^` without any trouble...